# Why am I getting an error about stats::model.frame() when passing an "lm" model to effectsize::effectsize()?

Tags: r, lm

I'm facing a strange situation when building a function that wraps `lm()`. Specifically, I get an error that pertains to `stats::model.frame()` when passing the function's model output to [`effectsize::effectsize()`](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/effectsize.html).

In the following example there are two scenarios, `A` and `B`. In `A`, I define a function that first builds a `formula` object `my_formula <- as.formula(paste0(y, "~", x))` and then passes it to `lm()`. This function returns an object of class `"lm"`. When I pass that object to `effectsize::effectsize()`, I get an error:

> Error in stats::model.frame(formula = my_formula, data = data_std, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
> object 'my_formula' not found

Strangely, when I pass the same object to `stats::model.frame()`, it works.

In scenario `B`, I build a function in which the formula is specified within `lm()`, rather than a preemptive object. In that scenario, passing the output to `effectsize()` works.

### Reproducible Example

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(effectsize)

## scenario A -- failing
my_lm_external_formula <- function(.dat, predicted, predictor){
  
  my_formula <- as.formula(paste0(predicted, "~", predictor))
  
  lm(formula = my_formula, data = .dat)
}
## the following line fails
my_lm_external_formula(.dat = mtcars, predicted = "mpg", predictor =  "am") %>% effectsize()
#> Error in stats::model.frame(formula = my_formula, data = data_std, drop.unused.levels = TRUE): object 'my_formula' not found
## although this one works
my_lm_external_formula(.dat = mtcars, predicted = "mpg", predictor =  "am") %>% stats::model.frame()
#>                      mpg am
#> Mazda RX4           21.0  1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  1
#> Datsun 710          22.8  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  0
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7  0
#> Valiant             18.1  0
#> Duster 360          14.3  0
#> Merc 240D           24.4  0
#> Merc 230            22.8  0
#> Merc 280            19.2  0
#> Merc 280C           17.8  0
#> Merc 450SE          16.4  0
#> Merc 450SL          17.3  0
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2  0
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4  0
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4  0
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7  0
#> Fiat 128            32.4  1
#> Honda Civic         30.4  1
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9  1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5  0
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5  0
#> AMC Javelin         15.2  0
#> Camaro Z28          13.3  0
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2  0
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3  1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0  1
#> Lotus Europa        30.4  1
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8  1
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7  1
#> Maserati Bora       15.0  1
#> Volvo 142E          21.4  1

####
####
####

# scenario B -- working
my_lm_built_in_formula_via_pipe <- function(.dat, predicted, predictor){
  
  .dat %>%
    select(my_predicted = {{ predicted }}, my_predictor = {{ predictor }}) %>%
    lm(my_predicted ~ my_predictor, data = .)
}
## both calls work:
my_lm_built_in_formula_via_pipe(.dat = mtcars, predicted = "mpg", predictor = "am") %>% effectsize()
#> # Standardization method: refit
#> 
#> Parameter    | Coefficient (std.) |        95% CI
#> -------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)  |           2.94e-17 | [-0.29, 0.29]
#> my_predictor |               0.60 | [ 0.30, 0.90]
my_lm_built_in_formula_via_pipe(.dat = mtcars, predicted = "mpg", predictor = "am") %>% stats::model.frame()
#>                     my_predicted my_predictor
#> Mazda RX4                   21.0            1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag               21.0            1
#> Datsun 710                  22.8            1
#> Hornet 4 Drive              21.4            0
#> Hornet Sportabout           18.7            0
#> Valiant                     18.1            0
#> Duster 360                  14.3            0
#> Merc 240D                   24.4            0
#> Merc 230                    22.8            0
#> Merc 280                    19.2            0
#> Merc 280C                   17.8            0
#> Merc 450SE                  16.4            0
#> Merc 450SL                  17.3            0
#> Merc 450SLC                 15.2            0
#> Cadillac Fleetwood          10.4            0
#> Lincoln Continental         10.4            0
#> Chrysler Imperial           14.7            0
#> Fiat 128                    32.4            1
#> Honda Civic                 30.4            1
#> Toyota Corolla              33.9            1
#> Toyota Corona               21.5            0
#> Dodge Challenger            15.5            0
#> AMC Javelin                 15.2            0
#> Camaro Z28                  13.3            0
#> Pontiac Firebird            19.2            0
#> Fiat X1-9                   27.3            1
#> Porsche 914-2               26.0            1
#> Lotus Europa                30.4            1
#> Ford Pantera L              15.8            1
#> Ferrari Dino                19.7            1
#> Maserati Bora               15.0            1
#> Volvo 142E                  21.4            1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Any idea why I get the error in scenario A (but not in B), and why `effectsize()` fails whereas `stats::model.frame()` doesn't?

Comment: What does this have to do with `environment-variables`? That is, why is that tag present?

Comment: @KurtisRader, I removed it now.

Comment: perhaps another way ... `my_lm_external_formula <- function(.dat, predicted, predictor){do.call("lm", list(data=.dat, formula=paste0(predicted, "~", predictor)))}`

Comment: @user20650, thank you. Your method does work. Do you mind to please elaborate whether you think this might be safer (or not) compared with methods suggested by `@StupidWolf` and `@Roland`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an lm object to effectsize(), it re-evaluates the call in your current R environment, and not in the environment where your formula variable was created, hence it throws an error since it cannot find `my_formula`

For `stats::model.frame`, since you are passing already the lm object, it just pulls out the model matrix, no need to evaluate, you can try passing it the formula:

```
x_formula <- function(.dat, predicted, predictor){
  
  my_formula <- as.formula(paste0(predicted, "~", predictor))
  my_formula
}

x_formula(.dat = mtcars,"am","gear") %>% stats::model.frame(data=mtcars)
Error in x_formula(.dat = mtcars, "am", "gear") : 
  could not find function "x_formula"
```

And you can see it fails spectacularly as well. So it kind of a wrong comparison.

You can force the evaluation of the call, see [this book chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#calls), but I am not so sure if it is the right thing to do:

```
my_lm_external_formula <- function(.dat, predicted, predictor){
  
  f = reformulate(response=predictor,termlabels=predicted)
  fit = lm(f, data = .dat)
  fit$call$formula = eval(f)
  fit

}

my_lm_external_formula(.dat = mtcars, predicted = "mpg", predictor =  "am") %>% 
effectsize()

# Standardization method: refit

Parameter   | Coefficient (std.) |        95% CI
------------------------------------------------
(Intercept) |          -1.77e-17 | [-0.29, 0.29]
mpg         |               0.60 | [ 0.30, 0.90]
```

Comment: Why do you think this might not be the right thing to do?

Comment: for this example it might be ok, but if you have something more complicated downstream with `effectsize()` it might be tricky

Answer (score 2):

You often run into scoping issues with `lm` and methods for lm objects. I've had good experiences with computing on the language but I can't guarantee that you will never run into issues. There are methods out there that just don't work with an lm object that hasn't been created in the same environment as their call, some bad ones even need it to be created in the global environment.

```
my_lm_external_formula <- function(.dat, predicted, predictor){
  
  predicted <- as.name(predicted)
  predictor <- as.name(predictor)
  
  eval(bquote(lm(formula = .(predicted) ~ .(predictor), data = .dat)))
}  

effectsize(
  my_lm_external_formula(.dat = mtcars, 
                         predicted = "mpg", 
                         predictor =  "am")
)
#works
```